# Converges given $e^{a_n} = a_n + e^{b_n}$

Tags: calculus

Let $\{ a_n \}$ and $\{ b_n \}$ be two sequences such that for each $n$ we have

$$e^{a_n} = a_n + e^{b_n}$$

If $a_n > 0$ for all $n$ and if $\sum a_n$ converges, show that $\sum \left( \frac{b_n}{a_n} \right)$ converges

Comment: It is generally expected that problems posted here will include some context, and not simply recite an assigned exercise.  Perhaps you could share what motivates this problem, or what difficulty you encountered in your own effort to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ is convergent, $\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n = 0$.
So, if $n$ is big enough, $e^{a_n}$ equals $1+a_n+C_n a_n^2$ where $C_n$ is a bounded and close to $\frac{1}{2}$. That gives $e^{b_n}=1+C_n a_n^2$, so $b_n$ behaves like $a_n^2$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ behaves like $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{a_n}$, than **cannot be** convergent, since its general term is not bounded.

As a further disproof, we may consider $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$, giving: 
$$b_n=\log\left(e^{1/n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\frac{1}{2n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$
as well as:
$$ \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 2n^2 + O(1).$$

On the other hand, the same argument gives that $\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ behaves like $a_n$, hence $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ **is** convergent. We also have an almost explicit inequality: since $\frac{\log(e^x-x)}{x}\leq\frac{17 x}{30}$ over $(0,1]$,

$$ \sum_{n:a_n\leq 1}\frac{b_n}{a_n}\leq \frac{17}{30}\sum_{n:a_n\leq 1}a_n.$$

Comment: Sorry, typo. I am still confused on how $bn$ behaves like $a_n^2$.

Comment: @MuhammadAlKahfi: you have $b_n = \log(1+C_n a_n^2)$ and $a_n\to 0$, hence $b_n$ behaves like $a_n^2$ by the Taylor series of $\log(1+z)$ in a neighbourhood of $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Limit Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test):

First observe that, since the series $\sum_n a_n$ converges, we must have
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=0.$$
Now, writing
$$\forall n\geq0,\ b_n=\ln\bigl(\mathrm{e}^{a_n}-a_n\bigr)=\ln\bigl(1+(\mathrm{e}^{a_n}-1-a_n)\bigr),$$
and observing that
$$\mathrm{e}^{a_n}-1-a_n=\frac{a_n^2}2+o(a_n^2)$$
yields
$$b_n=\frac{a_n^2}2+o(a_n^2),$$
hence
$$\frac{b_n/a_n}{a_n}=\frac12+o(1)\longrightarrow\frac12\in\mathbb{R}_+^*.$$
Hence (since $(a_n)_n$ is a sequence of positive terms) we conclude, by the Limit Comparison Test, that the series
$$\sum_n\frac{b_n}{a_n}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sum_na_n$$
have the same nature, hence the series $\sum_nb_n/a_n$ converges too.